# Short freeze/delay when pressing Super key to open the Unity Dash

Tags: unity, unity-dash

This is NOT a "slow animations" issue. It's just a delay; a freeze. The animations are perfect (with Intel HD Graphics 4000).
There are 3 ways of opening the Unity Dash in this Dell laptop. Two of them works instantly and beautifully, except pressing the damn **Super Key**. After pressing it, I have to wait approximately 2 seconds before it shows up and I can start typing. During that delay, the only thing responding is the mouse pointer. It happens all the time, not just the first time I open it.

*4-finger tap on the touchpad opens it instantly; Clicking on the Launcher's Dash icon also opens it instantly.*

Also, after I login, the desktop loads. However, in the first 3 seconds, the system is **frozen** in the same way that a Super Key press behaves, and all I can do is move the mouse pointer until it unlocks. Any idea of what this is?

EDIT: Running the system on an eMMC solid state storage device (fast read times, slow write).
And none of these issues occur during the live USB instance, only after choosing to install.

Comment: It is possible that you are having problems with your graphics card. By the way, what version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. This is one of those $200 laptops made to compete with the Chromebook (but having Windows 10 instead). Some versions come with Ubuntu, and this is certified by Canonical, so most of it works out of the box.

Comment: Have you tried updating your graphics drivers?

Comment: I haven't, because I thought the Intel drivers Ubuntu provides were the only ones. I couldn't find anything else available, but I'll look again.

Comment: Okay. Good luck.

Comment: The website for Intel Open Source drivers says that Ubuntu 16.04's Graphic Stack (i915) is already up-to-date, and the installer is only intended for 15.10. Recently, I gave Linux Mint 17.3 a try (based on Ubuntu 14.04) and it performed significantly better. But it's not really efficient for me in this laptop. I appreciate any further help.

Comment: I wonder if Intel graphics drivers are having stability issues like AMD Radeon.

Comment: Thanks anyway (: One last thing. The Live USB instance of Ubuntu 16.04 has none of these freezing issues. I could press Super and the dash would open instantly. System performance as a whole was considerably better. As soon as I start the installation, the delay takes place, and it persists until now. I'm not 100% sure this is graphics related.